# Can I use multi (sub) levels of relation (AND | OR) on custom query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy

I'm tryng to do the equivalent of:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'action'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'actor',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => 103,
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'horror'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'actor',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => 14
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Can I use these kind of multi levels of relation (AND | OR)? It doesn't seem to work on my code.

I want to request posts with `(genre action AND author 103) OR (genre horror AND author 14)`.

The following query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'horror' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 14 ),
        )
    )
);
```

It is wrong because it would give me `(genre action AND author 14) OR (genre horror AND author 103)` beyond `(genre action AND author 103) OR (genre horror AND author 14)`

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) doesn't show anything about it. Only one level:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

If it really doesn't work, what is the solution? It will need to code a 'the Loop' after another 'the Loop'?

Sorry if it is duplicated, I tried several searchs but I think I don't know how to look for it.

**EDITED**

If it really doesn't work, I've thought a better solution than Loop after Loop is convert everything to a MySQL query and use **Custom Select Query** as described here: [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query). Is that the way?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your main question but your own suggested solution will work.  It's a bit more cumbersome to write your own query and loop but you can pull the raw data and then filter/iterate your way through it w/o using the prebuilt WP functions.  Your page template would simply be a PHP script querying a DB allowing you full freedom for and/or logic at any level of complexity.  Someone else will likely be able to answer your original question as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping @jdm2112. I believe this MySQL query will work, but I'm studying if it is worth. I have to modify a LOT of things in a lot of pages in a third party template that is working very fine. I'm even considering just forbid the user to do this kind of search.